# How come a Pokemon's CP can exceed the value found by an IV calculator?

Tags: pokemon-go

If I use an IV Calculator such as [this one](https://pokeassistant.com/main/ivcalculator), then I can enter:

```
Eevee  CP 10, HP 10, Stardust 200
```

and it will say that, at level 12, the best, maximum CP for a Vaporeon is 965. However, I have a Vaporeon with CP 1069, but my Trainer's level is at level 12 (so when I try to power up the Vaporeon, it will say the trainer's level is too low. I will have to level up myself (the trainer) before I can power up this Vaporeon).

So how can the CP be greater than what the IV calculator found out?

(my Vaporeon is CP 1069, HP 131, Stardust 1600 to power up, but I don't think it makes any difference)

Comment: Bugs in third-party tools are off-topic for this site. If a third-party tool has a bug, report it to them directly.

Comment: I don't see anything about trainer levels on that calculator. The level slider refers to the pokemon level which is hidden in-game just like IVs

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because bugs in third-party tools are off-topic for this site

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your Pokémon's level can exceed your Trainer's level... I believe it is by 1.5 levels but don't quote me on that. This can easily account for the 100CP disparity you see, considering it's Vaporeon.

Comment: this IV Calculator seems like a highly used one, as googling "IV Calculator" will give this as the very first result

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol interesting... if I move the level bar to 13.5, then the "Your Best" will show 1069... so it seems it is true: the Vaporean is at level 13.5... but the it makes me wonder, if trainer's level is 40, then Pokemon's level will be 41.5, but the bar can only have a max of 40.5, possibly indicating a highest level of Pokemon to be 40.5

Comment: I believe level cap for Pokémon is indeed 40.5, but I could be wrong, as could the IV calculator's limit.

Comment: Whether the calculator is highly used or not is irrelevant; we don't provide support for third party tools.

Comment: @Frank isn't it true that you can calculate the possible IV using simply pencil and paper... so it is more like how trainer's level and Pokemon's level work, in math. It turned out the real simple answer is what Niet said, which is maximum Pokemon's level is 1.5 higher than the trainer's level

Comment: You could, indeed.  And we wouldn't help you with your math, either.  We'd tell you how the game worked, but someone making mistakes isn't part of our support in any sense.  We don't guarantee validity of third party sites.

Comment: While the question does seems to focus on the calculator, what the actual problem is that the OP doesn't understand the IV system and thus, the calculator he is trying to use.

Answer (score 2):

Ok a bunch of things...

1. The PokeAssistant IV calculator actually gives you **No combinations found** with the stats of `Eevee  CP 10, HP 10, Stardust 200`. The stuff you see for Vaporeon is just auto-calculated results and irrelevant because the stats you have entered in are **wrong**. In other words, 965 CP Vaporeon is not a standard to compare against.
2. Even if it were correct, you cannot compare the result of the IV calculator with another Vaporeon, because your 1069 CP vaporeon is a completely different pokemon with different IVs.
3. Any pokemon with CP 10 (like the one you are trying to enter in the calculator with) cannot be reliably calculated on the IV calculators:

   > So these are a bit of a pain. Niantic rounds up those formulas above to 10 if they ever score below.
4. Finally, as Niet alluded to, the pokemon level is not the same as trainer level, although the pokemon's max level is limited by the trainer level.

   > Note that Pokemon have hidden levels and each level requires two "Power-Ups"

   So this most likely means that your pokemon can be .5 level higher than your trainer level. Which makes sense because the max pokemon level is 40.5, while max trainer level is 40.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the question is confusing trainer level with pokemon level.  For the linked IV calculator, entering Eevee with 10 CP, 10 HP, 200 Stardust finds no combinations, but the webpage has a neat, dynamic feature where you may see a range of possible values.  Setting this feature to level 12 (hidden pokemon stat) is too low for the Vaporeon in question.

However, entering Vaporeon with 1069 CP, 131 HP, 1600 Stardust and the powered up checkbox finds a suitable range of stats.

So the answer is that you were confusing the pokemon's level with your trainer level.  The website's calculator seems to be working fine.  If anything, the maximum pokemon level is yet to be verified.